# How do I show which refinements are available for a word?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

The date datatype has a great set of refinements, for example:

```
t: now
t/second
== 21
t/month
== 4
```

How do I get a list of the available refinements for a word like `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words-of is great for functions, but what to do if your word is holding a non-function?

Well, you could try 'help.

It will let you down, however, for example if you want to find the accessors for time! values.

You could also try accessing via numbers, if all you want is to see what's available:

```
>> x: now/precise
== 15-Jan-2015/16:18:39.609-5:00

>> x/1
== 2015

>> x/9
== 15-Jan-2015/21:18:39.609
```

However, and I myself just found this out, this can also let you down; date! values have more than 9 accessors, but:

```
>> x/10
** Script error: cannot access 10 in path x/10
```

And even if it was complete it would still not answer the question, what are the available refinements?

So, I am here providing another answer:  Look it up on SO!

```
Type     Accessor words (and paths)
====     ==========================
date!    year month day time zone date weekday julian yearday utc hour minute second
time!    hour minute second
pair!    x y
gob!     offset size size/x size/y alpha
event!   offset
```

The gob! and event! paths are incomplete, since word and value pairs can be added dynamically, but this is a start, and what I've listed here will always be there.  (Actually for those two cases, just printing the value gives you the words it recognizes, similar to objects and blocks.)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a function, you can use words-of

> > words-of :now 
> >         == [/year /month /day /time /zone /date /weekday /yearday /precise /utc]

Otherwise the help command is the best option.

Comment: There is an appendix in the Rebol' documentation: http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html I think it's the best place to look for an informations about built-in types. Edit: It's for Rebol 3, but I guess it might be helpful.